# Format an arraylist

Tags: java, random, arraylist, string-comparison

I have a file that I am storing into an ArrayList and I can't figure out how to format it so that certain Strings of text are stored in particular indexes. The first line will be the category, second line the question and 3rd the answer to trivia questions. I need to do this so that I can then randomly pick questions then check the answers for a trivia game. All I get so far is every word separated by a comma. From the professor,

"The input file contains questions and answers in different categories. For each category, the first line indicates the name of the category. This line will be followed by a number of pairs of lines. The first line of the pair is the question, and the second line is its corresponding answer.
A blank line separates the categories."

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class TriviaGamePlayer {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<String> triviaQuestion = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("trivia.txt"));



    while(infile.hasNext()){

        triviaQuestion.add(infile.next());
}


    System.out.println(triviaQuestion);
}


}
```

Comment: Do you need to use just a single ArrayList, or can multiple data structures be used?

As it is, the add method for ArrayList makes the item you add the last element in the array.

Comment: Well there will be several categories of trivia questions and like I mentioned I will need to randomly pick out one question at a time from each of the categories to run through the game. So I guess that I could use multiple arraylists for each trivia category.

Comment: It appears that I need to use the split method from the String class in the java API but Im not sure how to implement it for my desired use.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the question so far, You would be best off creating your own `TriviaQuestion` Object which would look something like

```
public class TriviaQuestion
{ 
     public String question;
     public String answer;
     public boolean asked;
     public String category;

     TriviaQuestion (String q, String a, String c)
     {
         question = q;
         answer = a;
         category = c;
     }
 }
```

Then you have a few options, but if you have this Object then everything becomes a bit easier. I would create a `Map<String,List<TriviaQuestion>>` where the key is your category.

Then when reading the file, also you should use [`infile.hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) and `inFile.nextLine()`

1. Read a line (first I assume would be the category)
2. Read next two lines (question and answer)

   - Create new instance `new TriviaQuestion( question, answer, category)'
   - Add this to the Array list
   - Repeat until blank
3. If next line is blank, add list to map and loop back to (1)

Like: (this is assuming well formed file)

```
String line = inFile.nextLine();  //first line
String category = line;
while(infile.hasNextLine())
{
    line = inFile.nextLine();
    if(line.isEmpty()) //blank line
         category = inFile.nextLine();
    else
    {
         String q = line;
         String a = inFile.nextLine();
         //do other stuff
    }
}
```

Then to ask a question get the list for the category, choose a random question then set it to asked so it doesn't come up again

```
ArrayList<TriviaQuestion> questions = yourMap.get("Science");
Integer aRandomNumber = 23 //(create a random Number using list size)
TriviaQuestion questionToAsk = questions.get(aRandomNumber)
System.out.println(questionToAsk.question)
questionToAsk.asked = true
```

Comment: Not so sure how to use a map in Java just yet. But I see where you are coming from with the different attributes. Im still not sure, however, to read from that file and get the parts i need to work with how I want them. If that makes sense.

Comment: @Steven Eck Maps are very useful, get to know them when you get the chance. Also see my edit for reading

Comment: Here are the Java docs for Maps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

I've also added an example of using a Map.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by identifying what is needed. You have a list of categories (Strings). Within each category, there will be a list of question (String) and answer (String) pairs. From there we already see some "logical" ways to organize the data.

- Questions - String
- Answers - String
- Question/Answer pairs - Write a class (for now, lets refer to it as QAPair) with two Strings as fields (one for the question, one for the answer)
- List of Q/A pairs within a category - ArrayList
- List of Categories, mapped to a list of Q/A pairs - Maybe a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) would do the trick. The type would be: Map>

From there you would start parsing the file; for the first line, or after a blank line is encountered, you know the String will give a category name. You can call containsKey() to check if the category name already exists; if it does fetch the ArrayList of Q/A Pairs for that category and keep adding to the list, otherwise initialize a new ArrayList and add it to the map for that category.

You could then read a pair of lines. For each pair of lines you read initialize a QAPair object, then add it to the ArrayList for the category they belong to.

Here's an example of using a Map:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<QAPair>> categories = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<QAPair>>();
if (!categories.containsKey("Math")) { // Check to see if a Math category exists
    categories.put("Math", new ArrayList<QAPair>()); // If it doesn't, create it
}
QAPair question1 = new QAPair("2+2", "4");
// get() method returns the ArrayList for the "Math" category
// add() method adds the QAPair to the ArrayList for the "Math" category
categories.get("Math").add(question1);
```

To get the list of categories from a map and pick one:

```
// Convert to an array of Strings
String[] catArray = categories.toArray(new String[0]);
// Get the 10th category in the array
// Use catArray.length to find how many categories there are total
catArray[10];
```

Comment: Except you can't initialise `Map` as it is an interface

Comment: Fair point. Let's say it's a HashMap. TreeMap or LinkedHashMap could also work.